# Iterate through nested arrays with aql

Tags: arangodb, aql

Here is my aql query giving me the pathways to a specific vertex:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND @startVertex GRAPH 'courses'
    FILTER v._id == @target
    RETURN p.vertices
```

And it returns something like this

```
[
  [
    {
      "_key": "ADELPHI+UNIVERSITY==BIO+111",
      "_id": "courses/ADELPHI+UNIVERSITY==BIO+111"
    },
    {
      "_key": "BOSTON+UNIVERSITY==CAS+BI+108",
      "_id": "courses/BOSTON+UNIVERSITY==CAS+BI+108"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_key": "ADELPHI+UNIVERSITY==BIO+111",
      "_id": "courses/ADELPHI+UNIVERSITY==BIO+111"
    },
    {
      "_key": "UNIVERSITY+OF+NEVADA-LAS+VEGAS==BIOL+196",
      "_id": "courses/UNIVERSITY+OF+NEVADA-LAS+VEGAS==BIOL+196"
    },
    {
      "_key": "BOSTON+UNIVERSITY==CAS+BI+108",
      "_id": "courses/BOSTON+UNIVERSITY==CAS+BI+108"
    }
  ]
]
```

When I use the `FOR` operator and try to iterate through `p.vertices` or `p.vertices[*]`, it always flattens the array. Essentially I want to go through each array and return something for each.

Just like this python code:

```
lists = [[], [], []]
for l in lists:
    do_something_with_list(l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option #1:** You can use [AQL variables](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Operations/Let.html) together with a [subquery](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Examples/CombiningQueries.html) (nested FOR) like in your updated sample below:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND @startVertex GRAPH 'courses'
    FILTER v._id == @target

LET updatedVertices = (
    FOR v in p.vertices
    // here you can change the value of v as you want
    // in my sample here I convert a v object to a 
    // string representing it's _id
    RETURN v._id 
)

RETURN updatedVertices
```

**Option #2:** If you have a complex logic for the object transformation (i.e. if do_something_with_list from your sample is not that simple and can not be done with plain AQL), you can also use [User Function](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Extending/Functions.html). First step you have to register your user function, let's call it DO_SOMETHING_WITH_LIST. Then when you want to use it your AQL will look something like:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND @startVertex GRAPH 'courses'
    FILTER v._id == @target

LET updatedVertices = DO_SOMETHING_WITH_LIST(p.vertices)

RETURN updatedVertices
```

Note, the user function above must accept and array and return an array.